# is there a way to put multiple of the same function on a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to add more snowflakes I have tried adding the same function again and again but it's not really practical if I want to have like 100 flakes at a time so there has to be a better way 
here's the code sorry its a mess

```
    </canvas>
</body>
<script>

var c = document.getElementById("Canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var sway = 0;
var swayTimes = 0;

snowFall(100,);

var x = 100;
var y = 100;

function snowFall(time){
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(swayTimes == 3){
            swayTimes = 0
            if(sway == 1){ 
                sway = 0; 
                x = 102;
                console.log("bbb")

            }else{
                sway = 1;
                x = 98;
                console.log("aaa")
            }
        }
        swayTimes++;
        if(y >  0){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1500, 700)
        y += 5;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 6, 2)
        ctx.fillRect(x+2, y-2, 2, 6)
        ctx.stroke();
        snowFall(time);
        if(y == 700){
            y = 100
        }
        }
    },time); 
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this function currently just draw and animate one snowflake?

Comment: yea just one is there a way to add more in a simple way without having to make a whole lot of variables by your self